# How to increment my localStorage value by 1 on every page refresh in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

In my React app I set my localStorage item `count` with a value of `1`.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('count', String(1));
  }, []);
```

How do I increment this localStorage value by `1`, on every page refresh?

Comment: Get the value first, then add 1. I'm sure the documentation for `getItem()` will have been right next to the entry for `setItem()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increment the value of the `count` item in `localStorage`; you can use the following code inside your useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const currentCount = Number(window.localStorage.getItem('count')) || 0;
  window.localStorage.setItem('count', String(currentCount + 1));
}, []);
```

***[CODE SAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mystifying-goodall-rlxr5t?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css%3A5%2C1)***

---

**NOTE:**

You can also notice that page refresh count is incremented by 2 in development because of new `React18` feature<sup>[***1***](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074)</sup>.

*[Docs Reference](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development)*

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the value in localStorage, check if value already exists and increment if exists otherwise set to 1.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let val = window.localStorage.getItem('count');
    val = val ? parseInt(val) : 0
    window.localStorage.setItem('count', String(val + 1));
}, []);
```

Ref - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage